# GeoServer shows 404 error when CORS filter is added

Tags: geoserver, filter, tomcat

I am trying to enable the CORS for GeoServer. I am using GeoServer 2.16 and the Tomcat version of 9.0.8. I already tried to add following code in `geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml` file,

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>chainPreflight</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

While I add this code to the `web.xml` file, the GeoServer couldn't start. It shows the 404 error. I don't know why the 404 error occur when I added this `filter` in my `web.xml` file.

How can I find the solution?

[image: geoserver not working, 404 error]

However Tomcat server is still working. And the GeoServer log file shows following error;

```
2020-02-08 20:40:55,709 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***************************************************************************************
2020-02-08 20:40:55,709 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Reverting to java.io.tmpdir null for storage. Please set GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR. ***
2020-02-08 20:40:55,709 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***************************************************************************************
2020-02-08 20:40:55,766 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
2020-02-08 20:40:56,091 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory '/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc'.
2020-02-08 20:40:56,098 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory '/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc'.
2020-02-08 20:40:56,101 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2020-02-08 20:40:56,107 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2020-02-08 20:40:56,108 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
2020-02-08 20:40:56,108 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas.
2020-02-08 20:40:56,134 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 43 layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB
2020-02-08 20:40:56,159 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
2020-02-08 20:41:01,125 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded data directory: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/geoserver/data
2020-02-08 20:41:01,500 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
2020-02-08 20:41:01,510 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
2020-02-08 20:41:01,515 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
2020-02-08 20:41:01,696 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
2020-02-08 20:41:01,696 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
2020-02-08 20:41:02,105 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to set ordering between tiff readers spi
2020-02-08 20:41:03,188 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
2020-02-08 20:41:03,191 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
2020-02-08 20:41:03,342 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
2020-02-08 20:41:03,342 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
2020-02-08 20:41:04,381 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - destroy() invoked
2020-02-08 20:41:04,381 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - GeoWebCacheDispatcher.destroy() was invoked, shutting down.
2020-02-08 20:41:04,383 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota monitor shutting down...
2020-02-08 20:41:04,383 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
2020-02-08 20:41:04,383 INFO [diskquota.QuotaUpdatesMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
2020-02-08 20:41:04,386 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota statistics gathering monitor...
2020-02-08 20:41:04,386 INFO [diskquota.QueuedQuotaUpdatesConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to InterruptedException
2020-02-08 20:41:04,388 INFO [diskquota.QueuedUsageStatsConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to interrupted exception
2020-02-08 20:41:04,389 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Initiating shut down for running and pending seed tasks...
2020-02-08 20:41:04,389 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Seeder thread pool executor shut down complete.
2020-02-08 20:41:04,389 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageBroker] - Destroying StorageBroker
```

Comment: It seems as if you deleted a previous question from several hours back and added this new one with the requested information. It is far better to just edit the question, then toggle the `reopen` button, since SE can detect the delete/re-ask and may treat the user account harshly if it becomes a habit.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the log you have included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Jetty instructions on a tomcat server - try following the [tomcat ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363192/cors-tomcat-geoserver).

You need to add the following to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: this might depend on the server type, but on my EC2 Ubuntu installation of tomcat8 GeoServer, the web.xml is located in: `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/`. And even though it's in a tomcat directory, the web.xml has 'Jetty' CORS filters... confusing. there is another CORS filter written a few lines below it, maybe that's tomcat? Another web.xml exists in `/etc/tomcat8/` but it has no CORS filters to change.